# UWP - How to read .jpg from Desktop inside of app

Tags: exception, xamarin, bitmap, uwp, xamarin.forms

The functionality I am needing for my app is that if a user copies an image file (for example, a .jpg file in their Desktop folder), I need to extract that file from the clipboard and display it in my app.

I can already extract the storage file from the clipboard, and get the file path. But when I try to read the file path into a BitmapImage, I received a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` error, because the image is not located in the app's folder.

Comment: why don't you use FileOpenPicker?

Comment: @ColeXia I do use file open picker for other functionality in my app. But I'm wanting to add this feature as well. Skype allows the type of functionality I'm looking for (being able to send an image simply by copying the file from your pc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to open the file by path rather than directly using the **StorageFile** returned by the **file picker**.

Your app doesn't have direct access to most of the file system (including the downloads directories) and can access such files only indirectly via the file system broker. The StorageFile object works with the broker to open files the use had authorized and provides a stream of the files contents for the app to read and write to.

You can use [**Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/) or [FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker) .

Comment: You are right, I was reading the file path from the StorageFile, and then trying to convert it to Bitmap. Instead I was able to use the StorageFile object itself, and convert it to a bitmap that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may **x:Bind** path to XAML **Image**

```
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind GetAbsoluteUri(Path)}"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

Code behind:

```
    private Uri GetAbsoluteUri(string path)
    {
        return new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(path), UriKind.Absolute);
    }
```

Try, hope it'll work :)